# Bug in Reviewing Suggested Edits

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

I was reviewing suggested edits, just about to mark one of the "test edits" as vandalism, when the warning came up telling me to stop and pay attention, etc.

It's as though it approved it for me without me clicking anything.

I'm using Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m

Comment: This one? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3204750

Comment: You ought to be more *careful*.

Comment: Most likely you misclicked, clicking "Approve" or "Improve" by mistake. (both cause failure)

Comment: @laalto that's the one! :-)  I'll be more careful next time, but I didn't even get to clicking a button, all I did was scroll down.  Might be this PC I use at work, it has got a mind of it's own.